# Descriptive statistics with count of specific value

Tags: r

Most of the descriptive stats functions such as `describe` in Hmisc package give a count of missing values. Is there is a function for descriptive in R that can give count of specific values say Zero along with other aggregates such as mean, median etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not think of a read-made function that does exactly this, but you can quite easily create a function yourself. For example:

```
count_and_stats = function(x, count_value, 
                           summary_stats = c('mean', 'median', 'sd')) {
    no_of_counts = length(x[x == count_value])
    stats = sapply(summary_stats, function(s) do.call(s, list(x)))
    return(c(count = no_of_counts, stats))
}

x = rbinom(100, 3, .5)
count_and_stats(x, 0)
# count      mean    median        sd 
# 9.0000000 1.6000000 2.0000000 0.8287754 
count_and_stats(x, 0, c('mean', 'var'))
#     count      mean       var 
# 9.0000000 1.6000000 0.6868687
```

Adding the `summary_stats` argument makes the function flexible in which summary statistics are shown.

Comment: +1. For OP remember to be careful with `==` when you have `NA` values

Comment: A good option would be to add a `na.rm` boolean argument that removes any `NA` if it is `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks @Paul and Alex.  UPDATE: After searching a lot I found a function called `stat.desc` in pastecs package which gives count of NULL values in addition to other aggregates. For values other than zero Paul's method is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`table` does that

```
>x = rbinom(100, 3, .5)
>table(x)
x
 0  1  2  3 
15 35 36 14
```

Comment: This provides a count of all values, the OP specifically asked for a count of *one* variable and some summary statistics.

Comment: The question was edited after this was posted. It answered the question as originally stated. And, as noted, it does display counts of *one* variable - just no summary stats (which was the part left off of the question).